# Join or Union or Subquery or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which I need to join/union for a distinct set - but every query I've tried so far results in too few/too many rows returned.

```
table one    table two
ID           Type
Type         SubType
SubType
Percentage
Category
```

Table one is the main data set, table two is lookup values.

The data is something like this:

```
table one
1, A, ZZZ, 20.00, CAR
2, A, YYY, 80.00, CAR
3, B, YYY, 100.00, VAN
4, A, WWW, 100.00, BUS

table two
A, WWW
A, XXX
A, YYY
A, ZZZ
B, YYY
B, ZZZ
```

What I'm looking to end up with is the following data set

```
1, A, YYY, 80.00, CAR
2, A, ZZZ, 20.00, CAR
0, A, WWW, 0.00, CAR
0, A, XXX, 0.00, CAR
3, B, YYY, 100.00, VAN
0, B, ZZZ, 0.00, VAN
4, A, WWW, 100.00, BUS
0, A, XXX, 0.00, BUS
0, A, YYY, 0.00, BUS
0, A, ZZZ, 0.00, BUS
```

So, in other words I want all the data from table one PLUS any missing SubTypes from table two that match the Type of table one which would also include zero values for ID and Percentage, but keep the Category from the data set selected.

This works fine with an outer join if I only have one row in table one, but for each subsequent row my query adds more rows from table two.  I think I need some sort of union or subquery that is aware of other rows selected from table one so will only select non-matching rows from table two.

Any help most appreciated!

**Edit:**
This is my current query (the more I think about this the more wrong it looks)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.SubType = t2.SubType THEN t1.ID ELSE 0 END,
t1.Type, t2.SubType, CASE WHEN t1.SubType = t2.SubType THEN
t1.Percentage ELSE 0 END, t1.Category
FROM one t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN two t2
ON t2.Type = t1.Type
```

This gives me 8 rows - duplicated for each row selected from table one.

**Another Edit:**
Adding a couple more rows to table one I think explains this problem better.  So the SQL to create tables and add rows looks like this:

```
create table one (ID int,Type nvarchar(1),SubType nvarchar(3),Percentage decimal(5,2),Category nvarchar(3))
create table two (Type nvarchar(1),SubType nvarchar(3))
insert into one values (1, 'A', 'ZZZ', 20.00, 'CAR')
insert into one values (2, 'A', 'YYY', 80.00, 'CAR')
insert into one values (3, 'B', 'YYY', 100.00, 'VAN')
insert into one values (4, 'A', 'WWW', 100.00, 'BUS')
insert into two values ('A', 'WWW')
insert into two values ('A', 'XXX')
insert into two values ('A', 'YYY')
insert into two values ('A', 'ZZZ')
insert into two values ('B', 'YYY')
insert into two values ('B', 'ZZZ')
```

Comment: I think an outer join should have worked.  Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help on this, but I've worked it out myself finally...

```
SELECT ID, Type, SubType, Percentage, Category
FROM one
UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT 0, t2.Type, t2.SubType, 0.00, t1.Category
    FROM one t1
    INNER JOIN two t2 ON t2.Type = t1.Type AND t2.SubType NOT IN
        (SELECT t3.SubType FROM one t3 WHERE t3.Category = t1.Category and t3.Type = t1.Type)
ORDER BY Category, Type, SubType
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT ID, Type, SubType, Percentage, Category
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, Type, SubType, 0.00, 'CAR'
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.Type = t2.Type AND t1.SubType = t2.SubType
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue here is that it will bring back the two Type "B" records (table one only has "A" records), and Category won't always be 'Car'

Comment: How can you know what the category should be if it isn't there?  It seems like either some tables are missing that are needed, or something needs some normalization work.

Comment: The Category is part of the key data of table one.  What I'm looking for is all the Category + Type rows from table one with the missing SubTypes from table two for each Category + Type.  I've added a bit more detail to my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a `UNION`, just a `LEFT JOIN`:
**UPDATED FOLLOWING COMMENT**

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.ID,0) Id, t2.Type, t2.SubType, ISNULL(t1.percentage,0) Percentage, ISNULL(t1.Category,'CAR') Category
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.Type = t2.Type AND t1.SubType = t2.SubType
WHERE t2.Type IN (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM Table1)
```

Ok, this will give you the result you want, but its assigning the category as `'CAR'`, if you don't want that, then you should tell us what it should be.

Comment: This returns also `type B` rows from `Table2` which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: This looks like it's almost there - but it's the wrong way round.  I need everything from table one and everything (possibly multiple times) from table two where matches don't exist on table one.

Comment: Thanks Lamak - this will get the rows for the current data set - but if I add two more rows to table one - (3, 'B', 'YYY', 100.00, 'VAN') and (4, 'A', 'WWW', 100.00, 'BUS'), the result set would add the second "B" row with a category of "CAR", and would replace the original Type "A" / SubType "WWW" with row 4 of the data set.  I'm actually not convinced I'm going to be able to do what I want to do with just a SQL query.

Comment: @DJ O Then you should explain what should be in the category column for each row. Specially if you say that for the row (4, 'A', 'WWW', 100.00, 'BUS') the output on the Category column should be 'CAR'.

Comment: Sorry I'm not making myself very clear here!  What I'm looking for is all the Category + Type rows from table one with the missing SubTypes from table two for each Category + Type.  I've added a bit more detail to my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(t1.ID),
  t2.Type,
  t2.SubType,
  ISNULL(t1.Percentage, 0),
  ISNULL(t1.Category, 'CAR')
FROM Table2 t2
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM Table1) f ON t2.Type = f.Type
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.Type = t1.Type AND t2.SubType = t1.SubType
```